# Test if a JSON list is empty, and make a bash if statement branch on the result

Tags: bash

I want to create a check for when At times this api, does not return anything at all.

```
myjson=$( curl -X GET "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/" )

if ( ($myjson | jq '.applist, length' ) > 0); 

then 
    echo $myjson | jq -r '.' > myFile.json

else 
    printf "don't do anything";

fi
```

I want to check the length of .applist to make sure I don't overwrite the file if it is less 0 (0 would either mean the api is down or some other issue but most importantly it would not update my myFile.json )

if anyone could guide me at what exactly I am doing wrong in the if statement, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier here to tell `jq` to do the numeric comparison itself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# exit early if curl failed, no reason to do anything else.
myjson=$(curl --fail \
  "https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/") || exit

if jq -e '(.applist | length) > 0' <<<"$myjson"; then
  echo "There was content returned by the server; updating on-disk file..." >&2
  jq . <<<"$myjson" >myFile.json
else
  echo "There was not content returned by the server; doing nothing" >&2
fi
```

In terms of exactly what was wrong:

- `if` requires a valid shell command to be given as the condition. `( ($myjson | jq '.applist, length' ) > 0)` is not a command that does what you want; `> 0` is writing output to a file named `0`, and `$myjson | ...` is running your JSON *as a command*, not feeding it as an input string.
- `echo $anything` is buggy; *always* quote your expansions, as in `echo "$anything"`. See [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Also, note that even this version can leave `myFile.json` empty or corrupt if the program is interrupted while it's writing content to disk. It's safer to write to a temporary file (on the same filesystem, so the rename is atomic), and rename it over the original only when writing is complete.

Comment: Thanks, would i be right to understand i would need to remove "|| exit" if i had more curl requests being made in the script?
I figured, when it created the 0 file i was doing something wrong. I appreciate the clarification that it have to happen within the jq.

Comment: If you didn't want the script to exit as a whole, I would move this code into a function, and use `|| return` when you want to abort the function early.